# React state not working for Log in/ Log out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor, state

I am using constructors here in React. I am using the ternary operator to determine whether the user is logged in or not. Just a simulation.

```
import React from "react"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn = true
        }
    }
    
    render(){
           return (
        <div>
            <h1>You are currently logged {this.state.isLoggedIn ? 'In' : 'Out'}</h1>
        </div>
    )       
    }
 
}

export default App
```

Where have I gone wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax for initializing state is wrong, state is an object, so you should use ':' not '=':

```
import React from "react"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: true
        }
    }
    
    render(){
           return (
        <div>
            <h1>You are currently logged {this.state.isLoggedIn ? 'In' : 'Out'}</h1>
        </div>
    )       
    }
 
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: true
        }
```

Use colon its key / value object and not variable.